# Can you castle with white king if f1 is under attack from the enemy bishop

Tags: castling

The problem is:

According to one of the rules, the king cannot go through check during castling.

However, if f2 is empty, the king could simply move through f2 avoiding f1. Therefore not going through check, allowing castling.

Is the kings path in castling strictly defined. Or is he allowed to take any 2 square route.

Comment: The "path" taken by the king is strictly defined. [FIDE defines castling](https://www.fide.com/FIDE/handbook/LawsOfChess.pdf#page=6) as "a move of the king and either rook of the same colour *along the player's first rank*, ... the king is transferred from its original square *two squares towards the rook*."

Comment: This would not forbidden king from taking diagonal f2 route towards the rook, would it?

Comment: "along the player's first rank"

Comment: What do you mean exactly? King and rook would be on the same rank.

Comment: The move has to be "along the player's first rank." A move that takes the king through f2 is not a move "along the player's first rank."